# Is there a routine in MySQL similar to fn_dblog in SQL-server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, transaction-log

I already search about fn_dblog and it is about transaction log and it is used in SQL SERVER. if there any way to do transaction log in MySQL like fn_dblog? i can't find one

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use mysqlbinlog. Here are a few tutorials:

- [15 mysqlbinlog Command Examples for MySQL Binary Log Files](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2017/08/mysqlbinlog-examples/)
- [Identifying useful info from MySQL row-based binary logs](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/20/identifying-useful-information-mysql-row-based-binary-logs/)
- [mysqlbinlog documentation for your version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) (going by the mysql-5.6 tag you used)

Comment: okay, thank you. it's really helped me. Just want to ask a question, is there same between a binary log and transaction log?

Comment: @syabellrass that's another question, if this answers your question you should accept this answer